# rich:fileUpload allowFlash="true" not supporting in FireFox and IE

Tags: java, flash, jsf, file-upload, richfaces

```
<rich:fileUpload id="fileUploadId" 
                 addControlLabel="Add"
                 allowFlash="true"
                 fileUploadListener="#{ManagedBean.validateAction}">

         <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete"
                      action="#{ManagedBean.validateResult}" 
                      reRender="validatePanelId"/>
</rich:fileUpload>
```

The above code will work fine in `GoogleChrome`. I am having `Flash` support. But in `IE` and `FireFox` the Add button is not enabled. After refreshing the address bar, it works. How to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does it works with allowFlash="false" or do you find same problem?